# Imaplib ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, tkinter, imaplib

The following is the code I am using to create an interactive Tkinter Email Checker, and just overall Tkinter-based GUI for all sorts of different things I may need it such as calculators for different applications like math and electronic circuits

I'm trying to figure out the error: ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I'm unsure as to why I'm getting this error. It's probably something silly I am overlooking, but would be nice to get some eyes to look at and help figure out the issue

```
import imaplib
import email
import os
import math
from tkinter import *
from playsound import playsound



root = Tk(className = ' J.A.R.V.I.S. ')
root.geometry("500x500")

incorrect = Label(root)


class Mail():
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.user= 'personalemail@gmail.com'
        self.password= 'MyPassword'
        self.M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', '993')
        self.M.login(self.user, self.password)
    def checkMail(self):
        self.M.select()
        self.unRead = self.M.search(None, 'UnSeen')
        return len(self.unRead[1][0].split())

            

email = Mail()

UsernameLogin = Entry(root)
PasswordLogin = Entry(root, show="*")

UNlabel = Label(root, text = "USERNAME")
PWlabel = Label(root, text = "PASSWORD")



def enter():
    if UsernameLogin.get() == "fr1tZ":
        if PasswordLogin.get() == "papp0":
            codewin = Tk(className = ' CODING WINDOW ')
            codewin.geometry("500x550")

            emailwin = Tk(className = ' EMAILS ')
            emailwin.geometry("300x100")


            def series():
                serieswin = Tk(className = ' SERIES CIRCUIT ' )
                serieswin.geometry("300x300")
                
                svolts = Entry(serieswin)
                svlabel = Label(serieswin, text = "VOLTS")
                
                samps = Entry(serieswin)
                salabel = Label(serieswin, text = "AMPS")

                sresist = Entry(serieswin)
                srlabel = Label(serieswin, text = "RESISTORS")

                    
                sappend = Button(serieswin, text = "APPEND")
                scalc = Button(serieswin, text = "CALCULATE")
                
                scalc.pack(side = BOTTOM)
                sappend.pack(side = BOTTOM)
                
                svlabel.pack(side = TOP)
                svolts.pack(side = TOP)

                salabel.pack(side = TOP)
                samps.pack(side = TOP)

                srlabel.pack(side = TOP)
                sresist.pack(side = TOP)
                
            def parallel():
                parallelwin = Tk(className = ' PARALLEL CIRCUIT ' )
                parallelwin.geometry("300x300")
            def combo():
                combowin = Tk(className = ' COMBO CIRCUIT ' )
                combowin.geometry("300x300")
            def quadratics():
                quadwin = Tk(className = ' QUADRATIC FORMULA ')
                quadwin.geometry("300x300")

                output = Label(quadwin)
                output2 = Label(quadwin)

                a2label = Label(quadwin, text = "A2")
                blabel = Label(quadwin, text = "B")
                clabel = Label(quadwin, text = "C")
                
                a2 = Entry(quadwin, width = 25)
                b = Entry(quadwin, width = 25)
                c = Entry(quadwin, width = 25)

                def calc():
                    x2 = float(a2.get())
                    x = float(b.get())
                    c2 = float(c.get())
                
                    varrt = float(float(x)**2-4*x2*c2)
                    sqrvar = math.sqrt(float(varrt))
                    firstans1 = float(x) + float(sqrvar)
                    firstans2 = float(firstans1) / float(1 * float(x2))

                    secondans1 = float(-x * -1) - float(sqrvar)
                    secondans2 = float(secondans1) / float(1 * float(x2))
                    
                    output.config(text = float(firstans2))
                    output2.config(text = float(secondans2))

                    
                calcbutton = Button(quadwin, text = "CALCULATE", command = calc)
                
                
                calcbutton.pack(side = BOTTOM)
                a2label.pack(side = TOP)
                a2.pack(side = TOP)
                blabel.pack(side = TOP)
                b.pack(side = TOP)
                clabel.pack(side = TOP)
                c.pack(side = TOP)
                output.pack(side = TOP)
                output2.pack(side = TOP)

                
            def opencalcs():
                calcwin = Tk(className = ' CALCULATORS ')
                calcwin.geometry("500x500")
                SeriesCircuits = Button(calcwin, text = "SERIES CIRCUITS", command = series)
                ParallelCircuits = Button(calcwin, text = "PARALLEL CIRCUITS", command = parallel)
                ComboCircuits = Button(calcwin, text = "COMBO CIRCUITS", command = combo)
                QuadraticFormula = Button(calcwin, text = "QUADRATIC FORMULA", command = quadratics)

                SeriesCircuits.pack(side = TOP)
                ParallelCircuits.pack(side = TOP)
                ComboCircuits.pack(side = TOP)
                QuadraticFormula.pack(side = TOP)


            todolabel = Label(codewin, text = "TO-DO")
            todolabel.pack(side = TOP)
            calcuButton = Button(codewin, text = "CALCULATORS", command = opencalcs)
            calcuButton.pack(side = RIGHT)

            todoentry = Entry(codewin, width = 50)
            todoentry.pack(side = TOP)

            todo = Listbox(codewin, width = 50, heigh = 30)
            
            def append():
                if todoentry.get() != "":
                    todo.insert(END, todoentry.get())
                    todoentry.delete(0, END)

                
            
            appendlist = Button(codewin, text = "INSERT", command = append)
            appendlist.pack(side = TOP)

            todo.pack(side = LEFT)

            root.destroy()

            while 1:
                emaillabel = Label(emailwin)
                emaillabel2 = Label(emailwin, text = "NUMBER OF EMAILS ON ACCOUNT: ")
                emaillabel.config(text = email.checkMail())
                emaillabel.update_idletasks()
                emaillabel2.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
                emaillabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
                if emaillabel.cget("text") >= 1:
                    playsound (r'C:\\Users\brand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\ding.wav')    
                emailwin.update()   
                
        else:
            incorrect.config(text = "INCORRECT USERNAME / PASSWORD")        
    else:
        incorrect.config(text = "INCORRECT USERNAME / PASSWORD")
        

enterbutton = Button(root, text = "ENTER", command = enter)



UNlabel.pack(side = TOP)
UsernameLogin.pack(side = TOP)

PWlabel.pack(side = TOP)
PasswordLogin.pack(side = TOP)

enterbutton.pack(side = TOP)
incorrect.pack(side = BOTTOM)


root.mainloop()
```